# JBoss failed validating schema on startup

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I´m trying to start a JBOSS 5.1 within eclipse luna.
When trying to deploy my application, I receive the following error:

```
08:20:44,492 WARN  [SaxJBossXBParser] schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>. @ vfsfile:/C:/(...)/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_AS_5.11414613613116/deploy/mywarfile.war/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml[6,15]
```

I´m sure my JPA persistence.xml is right, because I validated it with the xsd using a external tool. That leaves only 1 option: JBOSS could not get the *.xsd file.

Since I´m under a corporate firewall, my initial guess was trying to put proxy settings (proxySet,proxyHost,proxyPort, proxyUser and proxyPassword) in the java VM options (inside eclipse launch configuration). That also did not work.

Any clues?

Given:
Eclipse 4.4
JBOSS 5.1 (can´t change to newer version)
JPA 2.1 + Hibernate

Answer (score 0):

This problem is because JBOSS 5.1 does not support JPA 2.1. Changing it to JPA 1.0 solved it.